# Script y me salta un error sintáctico " ´ ( "

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Más no puedo solucionarlo, tiene que calcular el salario mensual

```
#!/bin/bash
mensual=0
echo "salario mensual"
echo "ingrese el mes en numero, ej: agosto=8:"
read mes;
echo "ingrese la tarifa por hora "
read thora;
echo "ingrese el numero de horas trabjadas: "
read horast;
if [ $mes < 0 || $thora < 0 || $horast < 0 ]
then
echo "ingrese un valor valido\n"
else
if [ $mes == 1 || $mes == 3 || $mes == 5 || $mes == 7 || $mes == 8 || $mes == 10 || $mes == 12 ]
then
let $mensual = (( $horast * $thora * 31 ))
echo "el salario mensual es: $mensual\n"
else
if [ $mes== 2 || $mes == 4 || $mes == 6 || $mes == 9 || $mes == 11 ]
then
let $mensual = (( $horast * $thora * 30 ))
echo "el salario mensual es: $mensual\n"
fi
fi
fi
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. No resumas el error. Pon el mensaje de error completo EN la pregunta, por favor. Recuerda que puedes [edit] todo lo que necesites...

Comment: Tienes varios pequeños errores de sintaxis, pero aparte de eso no se entiende el cálculo que haces, pues cuando consigas que te funcione te darás cuenta que interpretas que se trabajan todos los dias del mes, en lugar de los habituales 21 dias laborables.

Comment: @masterguru eso es una suposición sobre el caso de uso del OP. Ejemplo: en mi país todos los meses se liquidan sobre 30 días y los años contablemente son de 360. Entonces no lo compliques más de lo necesario :)

Comment: @Alfabravo Al corregir el script y ejecutarlo veo que pregunta el número de horas trabajadas, que en su formula luego multiplica por 30 o 31 dias, y si bien acepto que en otros paises se haga de otra forma, me parece esclavitud trabajar tantas horas y todos los dias :-)

Comment: Te agradezco mucho tus comentarios, gracias por ayudarme

Answer (score 2):

El lío es de sintaxis. La forma de indicar operaciones aritméticas no es correcta dentro del let. Puedes tratar usando la forma `num1=$((num1 + num2))`. Lo otro es que las expresiones lógicas están mal representadas en esos IF. Todo eso modificado iría más o menos así:

```
#!/bin/bash

mensual=0
echo "salario mensual"
echo "ingrese el mes en número, ej: agosto=8:"
read mes;

echo "ingrese la tarifa por hora "
read thora;

echo "ingrese el numero de horas trabajadas: "
read horast;

if [[ $mes < 0 || $thora < 0 || $horast < 0 ]]
then
    echo "Inténtelo de nuevo e ingrese un valor válido\n"
else
    if [[ $mes == 1 || $mes == 3 || $mes == 5 || $mes == 7 || $mes == 8 || $mes == 10 || $mes == 12 ]]
    then
        mensual=$(($horast * $thora * 31));
        echo "el salario mensual es: $mensual"
    else
        if [[ $mes == 2 || $mes == 4 || $mes == 6 || $mes == 9 || $mes == 11 ]]
        then
            mensual=$(($horast * $thora * 30));
            echo "el salario mensual es: $mensual"
        fi
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Gracias! Tomaré en cuenta más la sintaxis, si me complico con eso.